# Junit vintage does not recognize logging level in Spring Boot Application

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, lombok, spring-logback, junit-vintage

I am currently using Lombok Slf4j in my Spring Boot application. Thus I have excluded the Logback which is the default logging provided by Spring Boot.
When the application is executed the logs are printed as expected. But when executing the junit test cases, the logging is not recognized. None of the logs gets printed.
The spring boot version used is 2.7.9
The logging level is set to logging.level.root=INFO in application.properties files.
We use @Slf4j annotation on the Java class. Then use log.info("...") statements to print the info logs.
Please find the dependencies in pom.xml below. Please help!

```
<dependencies>
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
               <exclusion>
               <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
               <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
           </exclusion>
        </exclusions> 
        </dependency>
          
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
          </dependency>  
          
         
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
       </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        </dependency>       
        
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
          <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
          <version>7.17.13</version>
       </dependency> 

       <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
           <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
           <version>2.12.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-text</artifactId>
            <version>1.10.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20231013</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>jakarta.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>jakarta.json-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
        
    <dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-core</artifactId>
      <version>9.0.83</version>
   </dependency>
   
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.26</version>
   </dependency>
   
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-autoconfigure</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.12</version>
   </dependency>
   
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.yaml</groupId>
    <artifactId>snakeyaml</artifactId>
    <version>2.1</version>
  </dependency>
  
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
    <version>5.3.27</version>
  </dependency>
  
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.parsson</groupId>
    <artifactId>parsson</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.5</version>
  </dependency>
  

    </dependencies>
```